# Why are these 0Ω resistances for?

Tags: resistors, resistance, pulse, push-pull

I was studying this circuit which is for a ±100V 3A pulse and noticed these 0-ohm resistors. As far as I knew, the use of these resistors was usually to pass over other traces considering a low current.

I am going to attach only a fragment of the schematic, the complete datasheet can be found in this [link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/md1822db3.pdf).

[image]

Comment: They have no electrical purpose.   Usually they are included as a way to 'jumper' traces on a PCB.  You could also potentially replace them with something else if your application called for it.    For example, you could replace them with a 0.1ohm sense resistor and use that to measure current.    They also make it easy to take U3A (for example) completely out of the circuit w/o having physically remove U3 or cut traces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an evaluation board for the chip, so they will often add footprints to allow the engineer to experiment with component values. If you look at evaluation boards, quite often there is space for extra decoupling caps, resistors, etc.

The purpose of an evaluation board is not just to watch the chip work, but to experiment on it and try stuff.

In this case, you could desolder the 0R resistors in series with the FET sources and put in low value resistors instead, then use a differential probe to measure the voltage across these resistors if you're interested in the current waveform.

I've done that on prototypes. For example, how much current does that chip actually use? To answer this question, when doing the prototype PCB layout, just put a resistor in the power supply before the decoupling cap, and measure voltage across it. When done, remove the resistor and short the pads. This is much easier to do if there is a footprint on the PCB.

Another use could be to tune the response of this ultrasound driver by changing resistor values. R33 is an example of this.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [populated PCB](https://www.microchip.com/_ImagedCopy/MD1822DB1.jpg), you can see what options these 0Ω resistors offer.

[image]

The resistors R31 and R33 are not populated and are shorted out.  But R18 is populated with a 1.1Ω resistor.

This is an evaluation board which allows the user to experiment with the components.  In this case the developers determined a 1.1Ω resistor was required.

The designers don't know how their design will be used so they provide pads to allow a place for evaluators to easily tweak the reference design to sort out problems.

Answer (score 2):

All resistors: having a resistor in these locations allows the designer to choose a value different from 0 to cope with anticipated design issues or variations.

All except R33: changing these resistors to a non-0 value allows to limit the current flowing in the corresponding paths (only the diodes are limiting).  They can also be removed to inhibit a push or pull behavior.  (Note: they are not suggested in the data sheet).

R33: changing this to a non-0 value allows the designer to change the output filter characteristic and avoid the direct connection of C18 with the output.

As said in a comment, these resistors could also serve as jumpers, but I do not believe that is the case here.

Such resistors could also be removed during the design phase to measure the current in the path.

Answer (score 1):

The can be used as a programming option, where they are inserted (populated) or not to enable or disable functions on a multi-use board; sorta like a DIP switch, but not readily changeable by the user.

OR, they can be in a location where the resistor value changes for different assemblies using the same pc board, and for your particular assembly they are 0 ohms.